# How to calculate average in rails app view through has_many?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to calculate the average rating in the view of my rails app through a has_many relationship.

Models:

```
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  attr_accessible :rating, :review
  belongs_to :user
end


class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible  :name
  has_many :reviews
  has_many :supplements
  acts_as_taggable
end
```

Controller:

```
@products = Product.all
```

View:

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
    <%= product.NOT SURE %>
<% end %>
```

I would like this to show the average rating for that given product in the view, but am not sure how.  Any advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your view, you want something like:

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
    <%= product.average_rating %>
<% end %>
```

Now you just need to do the average_rating, and that can go in the model:

```
def average_rating
    if self.reviews.size > 0
        self.reviews.average(:rating)
    else
        'undefined'
    end
end
```

So average_rating sums up the review ratings and divides by the number of ratings for the average. You can polish it up for format, etc.

Comment: Is there a way to do something like Product.average(:rating) in this method within the model?  http://railscasts.com/episodes/14-performing-calculations-on-models

Comment: Yes in fact there is and I wasn't thinking about it. I also assumed you had at least one review. I edited my comment to include the average and to check for a size of zero. You can't just do product.average(:rating).